# jmeter: how to use recorder twice for same jmx file to record 2 different scenarios?

Tags: jmeter

When you use the built in script recorder, it "writes" transaction controllers to the "Recording controller", where each transaction controller then has all the pages assets (images etc).

So you have recorded a few pages (e.g. a logged out user scenario), and modified some settings added "think time" between controllers.

Now you want to record another scenario, e.g. a logged in user scenario (so you can play back a mix of logged in and logged out users both hitting your site).

Jmeter only has one "recording controller".

how could one do this?  I assume if I "record" more pages aka transactions, they get appended to the the existing recording controller, so be played back in series.

Can the transaction controllers be "moved out" of the recording controller?  I have tried moving them to a new threadgroup, and it seems to work, but not sure if this is correct.

How about if I create two thread groups, and tick "run thread groups consecutively"?  Is it then possible to force the script recorder to use a different TG?  (one TG for logged out scenario, one for logged in) Can blazemeter handle two thread groups (as you have to manually enter the number of users in the UI, do you need to add the two TGs number of threads?

Whats the best strategy to recording a scenario in stages (e.g. if you want to record say 20 pages, and make a mistake, you have to start again from scratch - there is probably a better strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was quite simple.

After recording a bunch of "transaction controller" you can simply copy and past them anywhere, including under a new simple transaction controller (which is just a way to collect them together) or under a threadgroup.

You can also drag and drop the recording controller to a new place, and it magically records to the new location.

So two options.

Awesome.